# Is there any way to compile & test win32 C/C++ code online and download executables?

Tags: windows, web-apps, c, cloud-service, compiler

Is there any way to compile&test a win32 c/c++ code online and download executables?

If there is, I would be able to develop windows applications even on phone.

Any links or helps are welcome!

I found something.

> Upload compiler to Heroku?
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52465592/8614565

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want paid or free?

Comment: Free ones are preferred. But I 'll accept paid ones if there's no other way.

Comment: What's the point of compiling and get the executable on phone when you can't run it? typically if people cross-compile Windows binaries from Linux they'll scp to a Windows PC to run, or simply use WINE to run directly. If you want to develop then just write code on whatever platform then compile and run/debug later when you have chance

Comment: @phuclv You're right. I edited the question a bit..

Comment: @phuclv Seems like I have to wait for WINE 3.0 to be stable.

Comment: Upload compiler to Heroku? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52465592/8614565

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode There are a lot of free online compilers. So what are the requirenments? Should it be some kind of online IDE or just online editor?

Comment: @convert I think CI/CD in github suits me. Thank you for your interests.

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode Then you should mark that answer as acepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using github CI

You can utilize github's CI feature to achieve your goal.

1. Go to Actions tab of your repository.
2. You will see some C++ CI options.
   [image: Github actions-C++]
3. Choose the action that fits your need.
4. Commit the yml file.
5. You will see the CI automatically executes.
   [image: ci executes]
6. You can use [Upload Artifact CI](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) to upload the result to your repository's artifacts.

## Original Answer

> [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) is a hosted, distributed continuous integration service used
> to build and test projects hosted on GitHub and other source code
> hosting services (including GitLab and Bitbucket.org) on a Microsoft
> Windows virtual machine, as well as Ubuntu Linux virtual machines.

-[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppVeyor)

Answer (score 0):

Theres also https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/

and

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/github-codespaces/

Probably more.

With both of them, you could use some other editors on your phone than just the browser. Pushing the files to github starts the build.

Is this what you were looking for ?